# Code compiles fine in Visual Studio, but not in Unix terminal using g++. I get an error at the multidimensional vector. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

The code compiles, and runs as expected using Visual Studio.  I understand that never guarantees it will compile/run elsewhere, but I don't understand why in this instance.  Perhaps someone can help clarify?  The g++ compiler gives me errors at line 45 where the vector of vectors of type RGB are declared:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*  The following color method uses the provided formula to determine
the float value of each (i,j) coordinate passed as parameters.  */

float color (int i, int j)
{
    float col = float (((i & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x08) == 0));

    return col;
}

int main()
{
    // The provided RGB object that stores each rgb value:
    struct RGB
    {
        float r;
        float g;
        float b;
    };

    int w;
    int h;
    string filename;
    float c; // to store the result from the color method.

    cin >> w >> h >> filename;

    // A vector of vectors to represent the 2D array:
    vector< vector<RGB> > rgb(h, vector<RGB>(w));

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
        {
            c = color(i, j);
            rgb[i][j].r = c;
            rgb[i][j].g = c;
            rgb[i][j].b = c;
        }

        ofstream ppmfile;
        ppmfile.open (filename);
        ppmfile << "P3\n" << w << " " << h << endl;
        ppmfile << "255\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            // The following loop uses integer multiplication to output to the ppm
            // file the rgb values converted to integers on the 0-255 scale.
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
            {
                ppmfile << rgb[i][j].r * 255 << " ";
                ppmfile << rgb[i][j].g * 255 << " ";
                ppmfile << rgb[i][j].b * 255;
                if (j != (w-1))
                    ppmfile << " ";
            }
            ppmfile << endl;
        }


        return 0;
}
```

Here's the full list of errors that pop up in g++:

```
hw1.cxx: In function 'int main()':
hw1.cxx:45: error: template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type 'main()::RGB'
hw1.cxx:45: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator'
hw1.cxx:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hw1.cxx:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
hw1.cxx:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hw1.cxx:45: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
hw1.cxx:45: error: template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type 'main()::RGB'
hw1.cxx:45: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator'
hw1.cxx:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hw1.cxx:45: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
hw1.cxx:51: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
hw1.cxx:52: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
hw1.cxx:53: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
hw1.cxx:57: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)'
/usr/local/gcc443/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/fstream:696: note: candidates are: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
hw1.cxx:67: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
hw1.cxx:68: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
hw1.cxx:69: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
```

Comment: what is the error? (It compiles fine for me with gcc)

Comment: Which versions? My psychic guess is that you don't have C++11 support turned on in gcc, so the use of local class-types in templates is forbidden.

Comment: I assume line45 is this line: vector< vector<RGB> > rgb(h, vector<RGB>(w));

Comment: @PlasmaHH:  I added the error code to my original post.

Comment: @GManNickG:  The g++ version is 4.4.3.

Comment: You are also getting an error here: ppmfile.open (filename);
In C++03 you can only pass in const char *, so try ppmfile.open(filename.c_str())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I remember C++03 forbids using types with internal linkage in templates.

You should pull the RGB class from the main() function

Comment: There were several who let me know that what I did was not supported in the version of C++ on the system, but you were the first to suggest the easy fix of removing the RGB object from the main function.  That fixed the error.  Thank you.  However, now I am still getting an error on line 57 identical to the one in my original post.  I am assuming this is a C++ version incompatibility issue again with using ofstream.  Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/ _  there is no open(...), which accepts std::string. _  you should use std::string::c_str() function.

Comment: nvm, another friendly programmer helped with the second error.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In C++03 (which is almost certainly what you're getting with g++ 4.4.3) the problem is that local types and types with internal linkage can't be used as template parameters. In this case your `RGB` class is defined within `main` and isn't eligible to be used as a parameter to `vector`.

The restrictions were loosened in C++11 but I can't recall if (function) local types are still forbidden. Visual studio may be using C++11 rules while g++ is not.

Answer (score 2):

I see two errors:

```
vector< vector<RGB> > rgb(h, vector<RGB>(w));
```

C++03 does not allow this for a type that is "local" to your function so move the definition out of main().

Also the `open` function does not take `std::string` as an argument but const char *. So change

```
ppmfile.open (filename);
```

to

```
ppmfile.open( filename.c_str() );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with the second error.  I have already accepted an answer that was first to answer the original question, otherwise, I would have accepted yours.  Your .c_str() suggestion helped clear that up.